However large the natural number $k$ is, some consecutive primes differ by at least $k$.
The following is an example from a textbook on logic and proof.



I question the viability of choosing $n=(k+1)!+2$. First, if $k=1$, it would be meaningless to say $n+1$ is divisible by $3$. Second, with this choice, we should have
$$n+k=(k+1)!+k+2$$
in the third line of the proof. Third, is it really okay to address the numbers $n$ through $n+k$ as $k$ consecutive numbers instead of $k+1$ consecutive numbers? Similarly, for the statement to be proved, is it wrong to rephrase the statement as "No matter how large $k$ is, some consecutive primes differ by at least $k+2$."? Lastly, if the choice for $n$ doesn't work, is there any way to prove this existence theorem?
Thank you.

If $k=1$ then you're just trying to find $1$ composite number, so you stop at the first step: $n=(1+1)!+2=4$ is divisible by $2$.

Change the proof to "$n+k-1 = (k+1)! + k + 1$" and the proof will become valid.

Thank you, but does your choice make any difference? It's just a rearrangement of the book's choice.

@Boar Indeed we are not proving exactly what the textbook wanted to prove. If we were trying to prove that for any $k$, there exists $n$ such that $n,...,n+k$ are not prime, then we should have taken $n = (k+2)!+2$. $n$ is still divisible by $2$, $n+1$ divisible by $3$, up until $n+k = (k+2)! + k + 2$ is divisible by $k+2$. Thus none of those $k+1$ consecutive numbers is prime.

Please comment on (don't answer) questions boiling down to typos (esp. when they are dupes of FAQs). Answering them greatly increases community effort needed to process them.

@rafilou2003 I got your point. Thank you.
